# Exception of type 'System.OutOfMemoryException' was thrown when trying to add elements to a List

Tags: c#, out-of-memory

EDIT: Thanks for the help guys, I just realised that my mistake was putting number = (40 / i) when it should have been number = (number / i)... for some reason I had the number 40 in my head.

Also the missing "i++" in the first loop was me accidently deleting it while trying to fix the code :P

Original:

I made a method that returns the prime factors of a prime number under the form of a List of integers. However, when I try to fill up my list with elements, I get an error. Why?

```
static List<int> PrimeFactors(int number)
        {
            bool prime = false;
            List<int> primeFactors = new List<int>();
            for (int i = 2; i < number; )
            {
                if (number % i == 0)
                {
                    prime = true;
                    break;
                }
            }

            if (prime)
            {
                for (int i = 2; i < number; i++)
                {
                    if (number % i == 0)
                    {
                        primeFactors.Add(i); // <--- Error at this line.
                        number = (40 / i);
                        i = 1;
                    }
                }
                primeFactors.Add(number);
            }
            return primeFactors;
        }
```

Comment: That's because you reset `i` to `1`, preventing the loop from terminating.

Comment: Your first `for` loop does not have anything modifying the `i` value.  It will loop indefinitely with a value of `2`.

Comment: @JasonWhitted Though if input `number` is even (zero modulo two), the `break` is hit. Or if `number` is two or less.

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen OK?!  So it doesn't cause an infinite loop giving 50% of the possible input values.  Still a legitimate issue.

Comment: I can think of many problems with the code, but it could be interesting to know what `number` you call your method with?

Comment: @JasonWhitted Sure! But with his input, apparently he fills up his `List<>`, so he passes the first loop somehow.

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen Yep, that's why I posted this in the comments and not as an answer :)

Comment: One also wonders what the "forty" in `40/i` is supposed to be good for.

Answer (score 3):

In the first loop, you're not iterating `i` so unless `number % 2 == 0`, it will loop indefinitely.

In the second loop, you're resetting `i = 1` and then looping. So if `number % 2 == 0`, it will continue to add items to the list until you run out of memory.

Comment: Well, `number` is also reassigned in a strange way. But if `number` was an even number from the start, the `number` will repeatedly be reset to `40/2`, otherwise known as `20`. So I think it's safe to say that every (positive) composite even number will keep adding `2` to the `List<>` forever. It is left as an exercise for the reader to determine the behavior for all possible input `number`.

Answer (score 0):

You're getting that error because your second for loop is endless, so you keep adding to your List and at a certain point you don't have enough memory to hold it.
The loop is endless because of the i = 1; statement.

Also note you have another problem in the first loop, you are missing an i++ statement at the end of the for statement.